# Why does calling sp.address() with a dynamic value inside an entrypoint fail?

Tags: smartpy, error, contract, testing, string

Is there some way to call `sp.address` inside an entrypoint and pass in a dynamic String?

I have created an example contract showing the failing state:

```
import smartpy as sp

class DynamicAddressTestContract(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        self.init(**kargs)

    @sp.entry_point
    def test(self, params):
        sp.set_type(params.address, sp.TString)
        addr = sp.address(params.address)
        sp.verify(addr == sp.sender, "INVALID_ADDRESS")
    
@sp.add_test(name = "Dynamic Address")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    scenario.h1("Unpacked")
    c1 = DynamicAddressTestContract()
    scenario += c1
    alice = sp.test_account("alice")
    
    c1.test(address='tz1h4EsGunH2Ue1T2uNs8mfKZ8XZoQji3HcK').run(sender=alice)
```

The error is:

```
Error: Cannot convert expression to bool. Conditionals are forbidden on
contract expressions. Please use ~ or sp.if instead of not or if.

 SmartPy code line 18, in test (line 18)
   scenario += c1
 SmartPy code line 10, in test (line 10)
   addr = sp.address(params.address)
```

Why does this fail?

Is there a way to fix this or perhaps another way to achieve this objective?

[Link to Contract on SmartPy](https://smartpy.io/releases/20210118-6f466eee56038df8fda8b2f77819b83398346296/ide?code=eJx9kVFrwjAUhd_7K0Jfmm5SqNuDDArKKlMcwqaO4UsIaaqZNg25cdD9@iVNFN3D8hTuOfc7NzeiUa02CBqqjeoQBQQqitiRAqCyk7QRbFJVmgOsOZjnVhpNmcGgsvM9fYqQPRWvESFCCkMIBn6sB@ju7kD1DoLBHVfPnAeftajXxpbHLa4jqhXSXIDGZgaYopo2NyyVATfEdIpjL2bUTzpw2npltJC79OJ3IiqcFGx_utJr8jfXou6w7yl8lqy4HqBkvvyYvM5LMinL9@lqlfi@aOzBpB_Z7o3brDhsEIUVoo1UlB14FafR5XnhScC4pFq0fkSnkHMJpzeObJ_j@IrkNJbbvn_@65aA7gvb0ZfoUTB@lUkZa0_S4LgXAj1E9A4c1lUk5iffP07h5SRnww3P18PTEkZNvdiOPrft25d4mLFFkmb6JLFfXtEz0@gXS1_FmQ--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, `sp.address(x)` expects `x` to be a python string.

`params.address` is a michelson value of type `string` and michelson does not have any instruction to explicitly cast a string to an address. But you could probably do some "black magic" with `sp.pack`, `sp.slice` and `sp.unpack` to extract the address from a string.

The proper way to do it is to change `params.address` to be of type address and to remove `sp.address(...)`.

```
import smartpy as sp

class DynamicAddressTestContract(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        self.init(**kargs)

    @sp.entry_point
    def test(self, params):
        sp.set_type(params.address, sp.TAddress)
        sp.verify(params.address == sp.sender, "INVALID_ADDRESS")
    
@sp.add_test(name = "Dynamic Address")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    scenario.h1("Unpacked")
    c1 = DynamicAddressTestContract()
    scenario += c1
    alice = sp.test_account("alice")
    
    c1.test(address=sp.address('tz1h4EsGunH2Ue1T2uNs8mfKZ8XZoQji3HcK')).run(sender=alice)
```

Comment: i see, thank you for the clear explanation. i'm essentially looking for any way to compare a string version of an address with an actual address, via any intermediary type. as far as i can see the closest is to go from raw address > pack+slice to bytes -> encode to base256 > encode to base58 > pack+slice > comparable string but i am still figuring out the base256 and base58 part. there must be an easier way

Comment: Too much trouble **(byte manipulation is not great in Michelson)**. Also, you do not really need it.

Comment: while in 99% of cases i would agree with you there are always outliers, and in this case *i really and truly do need to achieve this objective* in order for the current problem i'm working to be considered solved, so i think i will skip base256 and try to use a straight up base58 byte to character map